# How to access super class method from another class?

Tags: inheritance

How to access the super class method from another class? I have the scenario below. Please help me.

```
class A
{
    void myMethod()
    {
    }
}

class B : A
{
    void myMethod()
    {
    }
}

class C
{
    B b = new B();

    // How to acces class A method?
}
```

Comment: Also, does `B.myMethod` *override* `A.myMethod` or does it *hide* it?

Comment: This code is a weird mix of Java and C++. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the super() function. In B, you will declare it as:

```
Class B : A {
    void MyMethod() {
        super();
        // Addition code...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as B overrides A MyMethod definition. You will need an A instance.